# How to GRANT permission to a user to read all the VIEWs in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, view, permissions, database-administration

I have a user named `Testuser` in a PostgreSQL 14 database, and I need this `Testuser` to connect to a database named `Testdatabase` and read all the VIEWs in that database.

Can anyone help me understand how to GRANT permission to `Testuser` to **only read all the VIEWs** in `Testdatabase`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `psql`'s `\gexec` in combination with the following query:

```
SELECT format(
          'GRANT SELECT ON %s TO testuser',
           oid::regclass
       )
FROM pg_class  /* the metadata table of all relations */
WHERE relkind = 'v'  /* is a view */
  AND relnamespace NOT IN  /* that is not in a system schema */
         ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
          'information_schema'::regnamespace)
\gexec
```

`\gexec` will execute each result row as an SQL statement against the database.

Don't forget to grant `USAGE` on the schemas as well.

To deal with views created in the future, you need a different approach. You could change default privileges, but that will apply to tables and views indiscriminately, which is probably not what you want. A way out here could be to keep the views in a separate schema and change the default privileges only for objects in that schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA myviews;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myviews TO testuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE view_creator
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES IN SCHEMA myviews TO testuser;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this query. The views are not yet created, so will this query apply to the views that will be created in the future?

Comment: No, it deals with existing views. You didn't mention that requirement in your question. You can use default privileges, but they will be applied to tables just as they are to views.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. Could you please edit the current answer or post a separate answer for my above requirement? I'm not sure about this default privileges.